# Flutter Firebase_messaging onMessage is called twice on android

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have added firebase messaging and it is working fine but on android onMessage is called twice.
I have tried to use workaround but it is not possible to find any work around for this.
When ever i receive a message. onMessage.listen is called twice.

I tried this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692330/flutter-firebase-cloud-messaging-onmessage-is-triggered-twice) on stackoverflow but its not working

I am using   `firebase_messaging: 11.4.1 and firebase_core 1.17.1`

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage event) async { 
print('received notification');
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that listen is called multiple times?

Comment: It is called once only